# How to align vertices to x=0 blender 2.9

Tags: transforms

I tried the popular method of snapping the cursor to origin and using it as the pivot. Then use S+X+0. Nothing happens.

Only the last selected vertex moves when I feed any other number than 0.

My vertices are almost 0 around -0.007617m, could that be the problem, that blender think they are zero. But there's still the other problem, it move only the last selected vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select all of the vertices you want to have an X value of 0.
- Open the side bar and hover over the X value
- type in <kbd>0</kbd> but don't hit <kbd>return</kbd>
- hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key down and hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much, you just ended a zero x blender nightmare of mine.